# Is it possible to define a virtual static member on a delphi class?

Tags: delphi, oop, virtual, delphi-xe, static-members

I need to create something similar which i implemented in PHP language.

Assume that i created a base class which define 2 static member variable, and then the subclass should be able to 'override' them so if i have defined the static variable "someStatic" in the BaseClass, and then i subclass to DerivedClass, when i call TDerivedOne.someStatic, the program should be showing someStatic from that derived class.. but that's not the case with Delphi, i definitely implemented it wrong..

For the time being, i implemented another design approach, in which the variables are not declared static, and then created a virtual abstract method called 'setup', and then this setup will be called on BaseClass constructor, but this design requires the object created first before we could retrieve the variable needed.

Now out of curiosity, i wonder if the virtual static variables could be implemented to save 'a couple of typing..'

Here is the code snippet of the problem

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}


uses
    SysUtils;


type
    TBaseClass = class
      protected
        class var someStatic: string;

      public
        class function get: string; virtual;
    end;

    TDerived = class( TBaseClass )
      (*
      //if i uncomment this section, then the print bellow will print the Base's static var
      protected
        class var someStatic: string;
      *)
    end;

    TDerived2 = class( TBaseClass )
    end;

class function TBaseClass.get: string;
begin
    Result := someStatic;
end;


begin
    // ------If the class is defined per unit, this one should be on the initialization section
    TBaseClass.someStatic := 'base';
    TDerived.someStatic := 'derived';
    TDerived2.someStatic := 'derived2';
    // ------END OF INITIALIZATION

    try
        //i'm expecting this would print 'derived' but it prints 'derived2' :'(
        //i am using DelphiXE
        //apparently delphi treat the statics differently from that of php's
        writeln( TDerived.get );
        readln;
    except
        on E: Exception do
            writeln( E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message );
    end;

end.
```

Cheers :)

Comment: There is nothing static here at all. You have class methods, and class variables. But nothing static.

Comment: hi @DavidHeffernan, thanks for pointing that out, i thought prepend the method with "class" and prepend the var with "class var" will make them "static" what's the difference with the "class var" and the true static declaration? does the derived's and the parent's _static_ point's to the same address?

Comment: Static has a meaning in Delphi different from C++. Here you have class methods and class variables. Static class methods have no Self, and static instance methods cannot be overriden.

Comment: I hate different terminologies used between different programming languages especially between Delphi and C++. One of them is that class and static huh.

Comment: @BasePointer I hate static in C++ which is used repeatedly in different contexts and often with very different meaning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem, as long as you override the `Get` method too:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  TBase = class
  protected
    class var FSomething: String;
    class function Get: String; virtual;
  end;

  TDerived1 = class(TBase)
  protected
    class var FSomething: String;
    class function Get: String; override;
  end;

  TDerived2 = class(TBase);

class function TBase.Get: String;
begin
  Result := FSomething;
end;

class function TDerived1.Get: String;
begin
  Result := FSomething;
end;

begin
  TBase.FSomething := 'Base';
  TDerived1.FSomething := 'Derived1';
  TDerived2.FSomething := 'Derived2';
  WriteLn(TDerived1.Get);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

For readability, I suggest to rename the private field in `TDerived1` though.

Or, use a `class property`:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  TBase = class
  private
    class var FSomething: String;
  public
    class property Something: String read FSomething write FSomething;
  end;

  TDerived1 = class(TBase)
  private
    class var FAnotherThing: String;
  public
    class property Something: String read FAnotherThing write FAnotherThing;
  end;

  TDerived2 = class(TBase);

begin
  TBase.Something := 'Base';
  TDerived1.Something := 'Derived1';
  TDerived2.Something := 'Derived2';
  WriteLn(TDerived1.Something);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: ah yes i see.. so there is no chance of getting that memory area without overriding the parent's get method? because if that's the case, i guess the method should be declared as "class function Get:string;virtual;abstract;" or maybe we should touch the vmt table still curious..

Comment: (1) Yes, there is, see my second solution. (2) No, because then `TBase.Get` would raise an abstract error.

Answer (score 0):

Since SomeStatic in all inheritances points to the same place, the last setting will be kept.
The closest approach to your requirements could look like this.

```
type
    TBaseClass = class
      protected
        class var someStatic: string;
      public
        class function get: string; virtual;
        class Procedure _Set(const Value:String);virtual;
    end;

    TDerived = class( TBaseClass )
      protected
        class var someStatic: string;
      public
        class function get: string; override;
        class Procedure _Set(const Value:String);override;
    end;

    TDerived2 = class( TBaseClass )
      protected
        class var someStatic: string;
      public
        class function get: string; override;
        class Procedure _Set(const Value:String);override;
    end;

class function TBaseClass.get: string;
begin
    Result := someStatic;
end;


{ TDerived }

class function TDerived.get: string;
begin
    inherited;
    Result := someStatic;
end;

class procedure TDerived._Set(const Value: String);
begin
    SomeStatic := Value;
end;

{ TDerived2 }

class function TDerived2.get: string;
begin
    inherited;
    Result := someStatic;
end;

class procedure TDerived2._Set(const Value: String);
begin
  SomeStatic := Value;
end;

class procedure TBaseClass._Set(const Value: String);
begin
  SomeStatic := Value;
end;
```